# How can I prevent pool pipes from freezing in cold weather?

Tags: pool, freezing

I have an in ground pool and we are supposed to reach temps in the single digits. Do I need to do anything to protect my equipment when I have the aqua link system with freeze protect mode?  Will it handle single digit temps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d try heat tape (or sometimes called heat cable). It’s flexible so you can wrap it around different size pipes, etc.

You can just plug it in when you need it or add a thermostat that turns it on automatically when temperatures reach a certain point.

The specifications for this one says it’s good down to -40F.

https://www.buyinsulationproductstore.com/pipe-heating-cable-for-pipe-100ft-long/?gclid=CjwKCAjwsNiIBhBdEiwAJK4khuCmmQn3pkO_qwwy0YvIjNyWHdy9Cqaw4uO_XEXubaRq6lxDQvnuUBoCUCwQAvD_BwE

Answer (score 0):

In my area pealing poles the round fence posts left over from making veneer ate painted black and floated in the pool to keep ice from damaging the pool, keeping the pump room warm usually protects the pump and filter with no pressurized or trapped water we have never had our pipes break due to freezing, before someone suggested the pealing poles painted black I used to use a large thermal blanket but snow and ice on top ruined them fairly quickly, I have been using the same poles for 8 years and have had no tile damage since doing this. But our negative F temps only last for a few days and it warms up in the day time usually.

Comment: No pump room.  All pool equipment sits outside.  Not worried about water freezing in the pool, just water freezing in the pipes.

Comment: The pipes in a pool system are not pressurized and they are open not trapped I have had no problems with broken pipes but 1 year I did loose a pump the freeze cracked a brass pump but the pvc pipes were fine, most of the damage we have had is broken tiles prior to floating the pealing poles.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you either keep your pump running the entire time it is below freezing, or  drain all the water out of the above ground bits you should be fine.

Comment: Thank You!  Shouldn't be difficult unless we lose electricity.  Then we are ALL in trouble :(

Comment: if that happens I'd drain the pipes immediately (and put on 5 layers of clothes)

Comment: In the area I grew up there is a new boat in someone’s back yard every few years when they drain the pool in the winter and it actually floats or fractures and fills with ground water.